# GraphDB history and versioning plugin weird behaviour

Tags: sparql, rdf, graphdb, database-versioning

Trying to go through [the guide](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.3/data-history-and-versioning.html?highlight=versioning) to use the plugin it looks like the filter behaviour looks inconsistent. After the three steps:

1. Inserting data

```
    INSERT DATA { <urn:Kirk> <urn:dateOfBirth> "2233-03-22"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> .}
```

2. Adding a filter

```
    INSERT DATA { [] <http://www.ontotext.com/at/addFilters> "* * !LITERAL *" }
```

3. Attempting to add data (that don't pass the filter)

```
    INSERT DATA { <urn:Kirk> <urn:dateOfBirth> "2633-03-22"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> .}
```

a query over the whole history (`SELECT ?dateOfBirth { ?log a hist:history ...`) correctly contains only the "2233-03-22"^^xsd:date", but a query to get a snapshot of data at some timestamp (`SELECT ?dateOfBirth FROM <http://www.ontotext.com/at/20220712161717> { ... }`) *does return both "2233-03-22"^^xsd:date" and "2633-03-22"^^xsd:date".

A bug, or do I miss anything?

Comment: Which version of GraphDB are you using? There was similar issue in 10.1, which was fixed in 10.2. As right now I cannot reproduce the problem with the latest available version.